# Can't Display Datetime on datatable Plugins

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I am displaying a list from the database, but the date time column is showing this error: 
`/Date(1492421931187)/`

JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "Default/load",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype" : "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Name", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Phone", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Num", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Date", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Message", "autowidth": true }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
var data = db.data_customer.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Message, x.Num,
                        x.Phone, x.Date }).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();

return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Json:

```
data
:
[{Id: 8, Name: "12312", Message: "123123", Num: 12, Phone: "3123132", Date: "/Date(1492421931187)/"}]
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) site

Comment: I think by controller, because json is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to change date format. Refer below code. In this code I am passing your JSON date value in date variable and as per requirement I am displaying date

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var dt=new Date(1492421931187);//Your JSON date
var getDate=dt.getDate();
var getMonth=dt.getMonth()+1;
var getYear=dt.getFullYear();
$("#abc").html("Date (dd/mm/yyyy)="+getDate+" / "+getMonth+" / "+getYear);
$("#abcd").html("Date full date ="+dt);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js">
</script>
<p id="abcd">Full Date</p>
<p id="abc">dd/mm/yyyy</p>
```

I have created a function which changes date format so that your issue will be resolved. I have updated my code in jsfiddle. Hopefully it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/GSB/b8bdjhhq/5/

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, but I'm having a problem with a "data" array displayed by Plugins Datatable, Date is a column, not a single value

Comment: I think date formatting error in controller, because the Json string returned incorrectly, is there any way to pass datetime to string inside Linq syntax

Comment: Please check answer.I have updated my code as per your requirement using datatable.Please find jsfiddle for same.